# Python regex to repeat a captured group between delimiters

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to capture a repeating pattern between certain delimiters. The string is something like this -

```
block 1
   <some other text here>
   element 1
   element 2
   element 3
   <some other text here>
   <some other text here>
exit
block 2
   <some other text here>
   element 1
   element 2
   <some other text here>
   <some other text here>
exit
```

I want to capture the block id along with the elements in them.. Number of elements might differ for each block, however the structure is the same.
Using python regex.
P.S., I dont want to use re.findall or split. The data is not this structured all the time. This is a pattern in a huge block, where I am trying to understand how to repeat a part of regex multiple times and also capture all the matches.
I tried this - block (\d+)(?:.|\n)*?((?:element (\d+)\n)+)(?:.|\n)*?\s+exit
But this captures only the first element in all blocks. Please help
[regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/fxnaws/1)

Comment: Can you add one or two example input strings and the expected captured data.

Comment: Expected captured data - group1: block 1, group 2: element 1, group 3: element 2, group 4: element 3.... match 1 should have the first block upto exit. Match 2 should have the second block with its corresponding elements

Comment: is regex even needed for this?

Comment: @AvinashRaj is correct. If the data is already well structured like given example, this can be done without a regex easily.

Comment: I dont want to use split or findall. There are a few more combinations that need to be met. This is only one pattern within that entire file

Comment: What is the difference between "some other text" and elements? How would a regex distinguish between them?

Comment: <some other text> is anything other than 'element \d'

Answer (score 1):

As your blocks contain arbitrary number of elements, `re.search()` function
with parentheses to capture groups will not be applicable. If you do not
want to use `re.findall()`, a good alternative will be a double loop
with `re.finditer()`. Would you please try something like:

```
import re

str = '''
block 1
   <some other text here>
   element 1
   element 2
   element 3
   <some other text here>
   <some other text here>
exit
block 2
   <some other text here>
   element 1
   element 2
   <some other text here>
   <some other text here>
exit
'''

for m1 in re.finditer(r'(block \d+.*?exit)', str, re.DOTALL):
    for m2 in re.finditer(r'(block \d+|element \d+)', m1.group(1)):
        print(m2.group(1))
    print('')           # just to put an empty line between blocks
```

Output:

```
block 1
element 1
element 2
element 3

block 2
element 1
element 2
```

If you want to create a list of lists using the matched results, you can modify the second half of the code as:

```
blocks = []
for m1 in re.finditer(r'(block \d+.*?exit)', str, re.DOTALL):
    elements = []
    for m2 in re.finditer(r'(block \d+|element \d+)', m1.group(1)):
        elements.append(m2.group(1))
    blocks.append(elements)

for bl in blocks:
    for el in bl:
        print(el)
```

Comment: (You could also use non capture groups :-) https://ideone.com/aIr7YJ)